# Error trying to preview a markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to preview a markdown document and Im having the following error:

> pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-67

````
---
title: "Statistical model for Data Mining exercises"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(mosaic)
```

```{r}
distance <- expression( (1- (1/2)^(1/N) )  ^ (1/p)  )
g <- D(distance, "p")
g1 <- D(g,"N" )
```

To prove that this answer is correct we can go [here]("https://www.derivative-calculator.net/")
````

**Error in Execution**

> ![Exercise 2.3 ]("C:\Users\John Hernandez\Desktop\Master Applied 
>       Mathematics\Fourth Semester\Elem_of_Statistics_exer_2.3_Sol.png").

Comment: This may be because the path to the PNG is incorrect. Does it contain the line break as in your example code? If so, remove it so everything is on one line.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: not yet. It isn't a line break, it's just that this line of code is so long and It continues in the next line.